# How to get two queries from firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I use redux and want to know how to take and process two queries from firesotre.

```
export function getBlackList(data) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        let db = loadFB().firestore();
        let query = db.collection('users').where("report.total_point",">",0).orderBy("report.total_point","asc");
        return query.get().then(docs=>{
            let result = [];

            console.log(result);

            docs.forEach(doc=>{
                let user = doc.data();
                user.id = doc.id;
                result.push(user);
            })
            dispatch({
                type: types.SET_USER_LIST,
                data: result,
                page : 1
            })


        })
    }
}
```

Through the code presented above, the component is processed through dispatch.

I get a query But I want to know how to get the two query values ​​together and sort them.

```
db.collection('users').where("memo",">","0").orderBy("memo","asc");
```

Is there a way to solve it using "promise all"?

Look forward to a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use [Promise.all](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query two values from a same collection, Promise.all is used to retrieve data from a collection group [different collections] instead of from a single collection.

In order to query [two values together](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#compound_queries), use the code below:

```
let query: db.collection('users').where("memo",">","0").where("memo2","<","3");
```

And after you can sort them:

```
query.orderBy("memo","asc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return multiple items. Get them together you can use `map` and `sort` if you need.

Then the call to dispatch for redux looks ok to me.

```
query.get().then(docs => {
  const users = docs.map(doc => ({
    id: doc.id,
    ...doc.data(),
  }));
  // .sort(...)

  dispatch({
    type: types.SET_USER_LIST,
    data: users,
    page: 1,
  });
});
```